# Problem using the pyperclip library on VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, pyperclip

I need my program to copy some text to the clipboard. For that, I thought of using the pyperclip library. But every time I run my code an error appears "Pyperclip could not find a copy/paste mechanism for you system."

I´ve experimented doing a simple program of the likes:

```py
import pyperclip

name = input("Enter your name: ")

pyperclip.copy(name)
```

To see if the problem was because of my code, but it turns out the problem still appears. So it must be because of the system/environment. I´m looking for any tips on changing something on VSCode too see if the problem stops.

[The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eM5lV.png)

I´ve tried logging into VSCode on both PC and Mac and the problem still occurs.

Comment: Does it work if you run the file from the command line?

Comment: I seems that you are running this from remote (on the error message, I see Ubuntu path). You probably need to install `xclip` on the linux machine `sudo apt-get install xclip`. [See](https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/). This is not related to VScode.

Comment: **I´ve tried logging into VSCode on both PC and Mac and the problem still occurs.** However, the path in your figure shows that you used ubuntu.